# How to proxy nginx request as in this curl command

Tags: nginx, proxy

In nginx, I can proxy request to https://ifconfig.co/ by `proxy_pass https://ifconfig.co/`.

I want proxy nginx's request to a [proxy mesh](https://proxymesh.com) before reaching https://ifconfig.co/

In curl, I can do `curl -x http://some.proxymesh.com:port -U USERNAME:PASSWORD https://ifconfig.co/`

Is there a way to config nginx accordingly?

I'm on nginx 1.8